# Can get data individual data from foreachLoop Umbraco c#

Tags: c#, umbraco, umbraco7, umbraco-blog

My code works fine but when i try to get data of each funds = subpage.Name i get all the funds data not as individual. what im missing here ??
Can anyone help me? im sorry im new to umbraco and c#, whats the best way to manage this

now its like this

```
(16) [{…}, {…},]...
0: {Fundo: "CURTO PRAZO", data: Array(21)}
1: {Fundo: "CA MONETARIO", data: Array(21)}
...

In reality it should be

(16) [{…}, {…},]...
0: {Fundo: "CURTO PRAZO", data: Array(4)}
1: {Fundo: "CA MONETARIO", data: Array(3)}
for example
...
```

this is my code

```
    var currentPage = Model.Content;

    var selection = Umbraco.Content(1448);

    @foreach (var page in selection.Children){

    if(page.Children.Count() > 0){ 

    foreach(var subpage in page.Children){

    var listaPdf = subpage.GetPropertyValue<IEnumerable<IPublishedContent>>("listaPdfsFundos");

         if(listaPdf == null) {

         listaPdf = new List<IPublishedContent>();}

        if(listaPdf != null){

        foreach(var row in listaPdf) {

        name = Umbraco.Field(row, "categoriaDoFundo").ToString();

        var id = Umbraco.Field(row, "documentos").ToString();

        var mediaItem = Umbraco.TypedMedia(id);

        url = mediaItem.Url;

        <script type="text/javascript">

       data.push({"Nome":"@name", "Url":"@url"}); 

        </script> 
         }

         <script type="text/javascript">

        list.push({"Fundo":"@subpage.Name", data }); 
        </script> 

              }

            }

        }

     }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use UmbracoHelper to get the IPublishedContent and then you can get the children of your content page & reach individual properties.

Please see details below; in my example my test content id is my Home page's nodeId and see how I get the children of my Home page and the first child's properties - so please update your code according to this, for further details take [a look at this](http://nurhak-kaya.blogspot.com/2016/07/getting-umbraco-content.html);

```
            var umbracoHelper = new UmbracoHelper(UmbracoContext.Current);
            var testContentId = 1353; // This is your umbraco node id of your content page
            var publishedContent = umbracoHelper.TypedContent(testContentId);

            if (publishedContent != null)
            {
                foreach (var child in publishedContent.Children)
                {
                    // This is where you can reach the Children of this child as well as individual properties of this child
                    if (child.HasProperty("emailAddress_Contact_Information"))
                    {
                        var emailAddressContactInformation = child.GetProperty("emailAddress_Contact_Information");
                    }
                }
            }
```

[image]